# Selecting all columns from a specific dataset after Join

Tags: pyspark

I have the following code. How can I select all the columns from df3 only after the join ?

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, col
df_dayOne = spark.read.option("header", True).csv("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/file1.csv")
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("agency", "agencyid").orderBy(col("load_date").desc())
df2 = df_dayOne.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(windowSpec))
df3 = df2.filter(df2.row_number == 1).drop("row_number")
```

Now I want to join the datasets as:

```
df_join = df3.join(df0, df3.accountid ==  df0.accountid,"left")
```

Now I want to select all the columns from df3:-

```
.select("df3.*")
```

But this gives me an error saying "A column or function parameter with name `df3`.`agencyid`"

Please advise.

Comment: please clarify a bit more on the error. Do you have the full error / stacktrace available?

I also cannot quite follow what you're trying to achieve by joining df0 as left join, only to then select all of df3, which you had previously selected.

Comment: i want to find all the records that are present in df3 which are not present in df0. Hence, I thought I'd use left join with the filter condition - all records where `df0.accountid is null`

Comment: Generally speaking - after joining two dfs, the resultset would contain columns from both df1 and df2. So how can I select only the columns from df1 in the output ?

Comment: Best way to achieve your filter would be to use an inner join instead. That way, you reduce df3 to those where accountid is present in both. (note that if you duplicate records for a joinkey, you'll get a duplicates)

as for your solution, i've posted an answer below. I was just wondering whether there was more to your error, because it looked quite odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend working with aliases. You'll likely run into select issues, should you have duplicate column names - which appears to be the case. Using an alias, you can use select all desired columns just as you described.

Over time I've adopted by default setting aliases on all my joins in pyspark - it just makes it easier.

So your code would look something like this:

```py
df_join = (
  df3.alias('a')
  .join(
    df0.alias('b'),
    col('a.accountid')==col('b.accountid'),
    'inner'
  )
  .select('a.*')
)
```